# Where can I find information about Boeing delivery history?

Tags: aviation-history, boeing

Where can I find the records of which airplane model and creation number was delivered to which airline in which year for Boeing (Like B737-300 number 32 was delivered to Lufthansa in 1980)?

Comment: Try something like the construction lists at https://www.planelogger.com/Aircraft - that will show every aircraft in order of production, and who it was delivered to, although you'll need to click each entry to see the delivery dates.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann I think this is a good question, but to satisfy those who claim the question is too broad, you might consider narrowing down to one or a few manufacturers, if that would meet your research criterion.

Comment: http://www.airfleets.net/

Comment: resources location is off-topic as defined by the [help center](/help/on-topic). You'd better ask "What are the livery historically used by Lufthansa on the 737?". Good answer will provide resources for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

[Planespotters.net](http://www.planespotters.net/production-list/index) also has a nice list. It has a good layout, and has pictures.